# VB.NET VisualStyleRenderer ThemeBackground missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-styles

I am trying to port my VB6 code to .NET, but there is something that I just don't find:

In VB6 I said (pseudo-code)

```
OpenThemeData "ExplorerBar"
```

and then...

```
DrawThemeBackground Lib "UxTheme.dll" (ByVal hTheme As IntPtr, ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal iPartId As Integer, ByVal iStateId As Integer, ByRef pRect As RECT, ByRef pClipRect As RECT) As Integer
```

Now with .NET I just don't find that background.

```
    Dim renderer As VisualStyleRenderer
    renderer = New VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.ExplorerBar.NormalGroupBackground.Normal)
```

I think I tried all available under "ExplorerBar", but none gave me the same result as in VB6.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
renderer = New VisualStyleRenderer("ExplorerBar", 0, 0)
```